# Signal Averaging

Tags: summation, signal-processing, average

**Note I also asked [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/61026/signal-averaging) on signal processing stackexchange** If this question does not belong here as well I will delete it

I was reading a wiki page about [signal averaging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_averaging#Signal_power_for_sampled_signals) specifically in the section Signal power for sampled signals. At least at first glance the information seems to be quite wrong.

Passage from wikipedia follows:

Considering $n$vectors $V_i,\,i \in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ of signal samples of length $T$
$V_i = \left[s_{i,1}, \ldots, s_{i,T}\right],\quad s_{i,k} \in \mathbb K^T$,

the power $P_i$ of such a vector simply is

$P_i = \sum_{k=1}^T {s_{i,k}^2} = \left| V_i \right|^2$.

Again, averaging the $n$ vectors $V_{i},\,i=1,\ldots,n$, yields the following averaged vector

$V_\text{avg} = \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^T\sum_{i=1}^n s_{i,k}=  \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^T s_{i,k}$.

In the case where $V_n \equiv V_m \forall m,n \in \{ 1,\ldots, n\}$, we see that $V_\text{avg}$ reaches a maximum of

$V_\text{avg, identical signals} = P_i$.

In this case, the ratio of signal to noise also reaches a maximum,

$ \text{SNR}_\text{avg, identical signals} = \frac{V_\text{avg, identical signals}}{N_\text{avg}} = n \text{SNR}$.

This is the oversampling case, where the observed signal is correlated (because oversampling implies that the signal observations are strongly correlated).

Firstly, doesn't $$V_i = \left[s_{i,1}, \ldots, s_{i,T}\right],\quad s_{i,k} \in \mathbb K^T$$

Imply that $V_i$ is actually a vector of functions, $f:T\rightarrow K$ which is not what I think the intended meaning is. Shouldn't $V_i \in K^T$ and $s_{i,k} \in K$? Secondly, for $$V_\text{avg} = \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^T\sum_{i=1}^n s_{i,k}=  \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^T s_{i,k}$$ Isn't this just a scalar since they summed all the vectors and over the vectors? How is this the average vector? It may be that I don't understand something here but I feel like this section is full of mistakes and poorly explains whats going on. Am I correct that this is a mistake in the page or is there something I don't understand?

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not your question belongs here. Regardless, please update your question to provide a link to the same question you posted on signal processing Stack Exchange. This will make it easy for anybody interested in commenting on or answering your question to check the other site's question to help ensure they are avoiding duplicating efforts. Thanks.

Comment: Good call. I’m not sure if it does either I only asked it here because I have a lab due tommorow and there is very limited material online so it was a bit time sensitive

Comment: Thanks for making that change. I just checked the other site's question to see there's no link to this one there. To likewise help anybody there avoid duplicating efforts, you may wish to provide a link there to this question here. Also, note it's generally frowned on to post the same question on multiple sites too close together in time, especially basically just a few hours apart. You may wish to make it clear in both question texts about you doing this for the reasons you just wrote above in your comment.

Comment: Also a good idea. My main concern is that from what it seems either this wiki page has problems, or my lab does and due to limited online material it is hard to confirm which it is. It’s also difficult to get further information about it so It’s harder to workout myself.

Comment: This is a poorly written and confusing wiki article. The "signal power for sampled signals" section in particular, is terribly written ($\mathbb{K}$ is not defined, $\mathbb{K}^T$ should be $\mathbb{K}$, the notion of oversampling is randomly thrown in, etc).